# Lubuntu - remap keys without logout

Tags: lubuntu

To remap keys under [Lubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu), I need to modify `lxde-rc.xml` file and next time I login, I should have the new key configuration (as written [here](http://stray-notes.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/lxde-remap-keyboard-shortcuts.html))

Can I reload the new key configuration without logging out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on desktop and choose "Desktop preferences", then go to "Advanced" tab, and check "Show windows manager menu" (WARNING! do not close this dialog window).

Now right click on the desktop and choose "Restart", then uncheck "Show windows manager menu" and close the dialog window. (If you loose the dialog for some reason, you can show it with `pcmanfm --desktop-pref`).

As an alternative, you can use [`obkey`](http://code.google.com/p/obkey/), an application that provide a GUI to modify keybindings in openbox on the fly.

Answer (score 13):

Command `openbox --reconfigure` seems to do the trick without logging out.

Comment: In lubuntu I got an error message, but it works.
Obt-Message: Failed to open an Input Method

Comment: Worked perfectly for me on Lubuntu 16.04, and is a simpler answer than the accepted one.